# Cannot declare variable to be of abstract type because the virtual functions are pure - with multiple inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, abstract-class, abstract

I have seen multiple answers for this kind of problem but I don't get how to resolve it. The main problem is probably that I'm working on someone else's code, but meh. Here is a reduced sample for this problem:
I have one class that links many other classes:

```
class Interface
  : public system_atoms,
    public system_io,
    /* etc, others */
{
/* A few functions, none that matters here - none from the inherited classes redefined */
}
```

Inside system_atoms, I have:

```
class system_atoms {
public:
    virtual int init_atom(int atom_number) = 0;
    virtual int check_atom_id(int atom_number) = 0;
}
```

And I have a class that should inherit from Interface:

```
class Interface_proxy : public Interface {
public: 
/* stuff - no function from the inherited classes redefined */
}
```

In the .cpp:

```
Interface_proxy global_interface_proxy;
```

Compilation brings an error stating "*Cannot declare variable `global_interface_proxy` to be of abstract type `Interface_proxy` because the virtual functions [the two listed in system_atoms] are pure*".

I'm not really proficient in c++ either. I guess that I should redefine the two virtual functions as pure (the same without the `= 0` and the `virtual` right ?) somewhere so that the variable isn't of abstract type. But my knowledge stops there - and the multiple inheritance just confuses me.

Comment: You can not create an instance of a class if that class has pure virtual methods. It is called an abstract class. All derived classes have to either implement those methods or they will be abstract too.

Comment: Even without the mutliple inheritence you will get the same error. If you wan to declare an `Interface_proxy` it will need to be a pointer or reference, and then you will have to point to or refre to actual non-abstract (e.g. Interface_proxy) which does implement the pure fns.

Answer (score 4):

A [pure virtual function](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/abstract_class) is a function that is virtual and that explicitly has no implementation (denoted with the trailing `= 0`). A pure virtual function is intended to force derived classes to provide their own implementation for that function. In other words, a derived class is expected to eventually define its own behavior for that function.

An abstract class is a class that has one or more pure virtual functions, either because it declares at least one or it inherits from an abstract class and does not override all of the inherited pure virtual functions. These classes cannot be instantiated (you cannot create an instance of it) since their behavior is not fully defined. They can only be used as base classes for other types.

In your case, `system_atoms` defines 2 pure virtual functions so it's an abstract class. Each of the classes you've listed that inherits from `system_atoms` is also abstract since they all inherit from those pure virtual functions and never override them.

The correct solution is to provide an implementation for those pure virtual functions in your derived class by overriding.

See the [virtual functions](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)
 and the [`override`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/override) specifier.

Multiple inheritance does not come into play here, except that each inherited class may have its own pure virtual functions. Simply override the pure virtual functions normally.

Comment: Thanks. If I understood this correctly, I therefore need to override these two functions in Interface_proxy, something like `int init_atom(int atom_number) override;`.

Comment: @Marlon Yes, and for `check_atom_id`. And then you have to implement them. You may need to reflect on what an appropriate behavior is for those methods for your case.

Comment: best answer ever